# Remove “Compare Prod” SideBar from Catalog XML?

Tags: magento-1.8

I edited the **catalog.xml** file but still NOT working !!

Folder: `/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml`

**Code Removed:** 
**Line 56** `<block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" before="cart_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>`

**Line 166** `<action method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.compare.sidebar</name></action>`

**QTN:** Is it the correct Folder ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

base/default is basically a core package/theme. Modifying it is generally considered a Bad Idea. Also, it's usually just a fallback of real theme, such as rwd/default (Magento CE 1.9) or default/default (earlier versions). Modifying your own theme or better yet, using local layout update file (local.xml) is highly recommended.

Simplest way perhaps is to use remove command.:

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar" />
    </default>
</layout>
```

Please note that  means that the sidebar is removed from ALL pages.

Comment: My local.xml is NOT working !!  I tried to remove the Disc Coupon / Shipping Blk - AND DID'NT WORK !!!

Comment: As I suggested you're probably experimenting on local.xml of wrong theme. base/default theme is the failover theme.

Answer (score 3):

Never edit the base theme files!

Use an local.xml in your theme (pathtoyourtheme/layout/local.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.compare.sidebar</name></action>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Answer (score -1):

**`<remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar"/>`**

add this line where you want to remove.

```
<reference name="left">
     <remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar"/>
</reference>
```

Comment: `<remove />` works at the layout level, so it never belongs in a `<reference />`